# Limit OwnCloud/Apache/WebDAV upload speed

Tags: apache2, webdav, owncloud, rate-limiting

So well hello!

I recently set up my OwnCloud on my Server and came across 2 problems...

The first problem was, how do I limit the download speed of users? Okay.. solved with mod_bw.

The second problem is..... how do I limit the UPLOAD speed of users? Okey.. tried it with cband, bw, rate-limit. Nothing works, only for download speeds.

So my question is, how can I limit the UPLOAD speed of a file TO the apache server for only a subfolder (i managed that with download speed, so probably with Location?).

Thank you!

Comment: Hello Nicolas. Everybody is glad that you solved your first and second problems but full log of successfuly solved tasks is not needed. My suggestion: edit your post, make your **actual** question more clear.

Comment: ??? I did not solve the second problem.. thats my question. Sorry if its unclear.

Comment: `Second problem was.....` - I understood that it `was` and now it's not a problem. You see? Edit your post and remove everything that's not about your problem now.

Comment: Yeah yeah.. changed it to "is", more clear? Also "So my questions is....." thats the question

Comment: Yes, it's more clear but I'm still wondering how First problem already solved with mod_bw is related to your problem **now**. I suppose that your question will be better without that paragraph.

Comment: Well okay... and do you know anything according to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it it helps but in the Nextcloud Desktop Client you can configure the maximum upload and download speed.

Comment: Well, im using OwnCloud :/ And yes, I know there is in the Desktop Client. But I want to have the Limit for EVERYONE and also on the WebClient.